# Trouble getting Heroku App to run but I can get it to run locally

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, netlify

Says that webpack compiled successfully when I enter `git push heroku main` but when I check `heroku logs --tail` it shows that my build failed and the link to my app goes to the default initial heroku page.

I've tried updating my webpack.config.js by adding

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
```

And then removing all my extensions on my actual React components like so

```
Before:
import SearchContainer from './SearchContainer.jsx';
import Promoted from './Promoted.jsx';
import Products from './Products.jsx';
After:
import SearchContainer from './SearchContainer';
import Promoted from './Promoted';
import Products from './Products';
```

I've also double-checked my files for case sensitivity multiple times, making sure to re-add the files on git using the below command and back checked that everything matched:

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git add .
```

Really stumped on this. A link to my application is [here](https://github.com/marissaromero/duffl). A similar thing happened when I tried to deploy on Netlify. Everything works locally and then crashes when running on the sites. I switched to Heroku after attempting to debug Netlfiy for most of the day. If anyone has a solution for any either I'd really appreciate it. Below is the error message I get from Netlify, which might be helpful debugging what's happening with Heroku since Heroku isn't descriptive in its build fail output.

```
7:14:01 PM: ERROR in main
7:14:01 PM: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/opt/build/repo'
resolve 'babel-loader' in '/opt/build/repo'
7:14:01 PM:   Parsed request is a module
7:14:01 PM:   using description file: /package.json (relative path: .opt/build/repo)
7:14:01 PM:     resolve as module
7:14:01 PM:       /opt/build/repo/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /opt/build/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /opt/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
7:14:01 PM: webpack 5.30.0 compiled with 1 error in 54 ms
7:14:01 PM: assets by status 670 bytes [cached] 1 asset
7:14:01 PM: ERROR in main
7:14:01 PM: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './client/src/index' in '/opt/build/repo'
resolve './client/src/index' in '/opt/build/repo'
7:14:01 PM:   using description file: /package.json (relative path: .opt/build/repo)
7:14:01 PM:     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /package.json (relative path: .opt/build/repo/client/src/index)
7:14:01 PM:       no extension
7:14:01 PM:         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /opt/build/repo/client/src/index doesn't exist
      .js
7:14:01 PM:         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /opt/build/repo/client/src/index.js doesn't exist
      .jsx
7:14:01 PM:         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /opt/build/repo/client/src/index.jsx doesn't exist
      as directory
7:14:01 PM:         /opt/build/repo/client/src/index doesn't exist
7:14:01 PM: webpack 5.30.0 compiled with 1 error in 11 ms
7:14:06 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things that I would recommend:

1. `build` command has a `--watch` option. The watcher might be needed for your local development but it is not on the server. It just hangs in the build pipeline and potentially times-out the build. Have two `webpack` configs (from one common one); one for development and one for production (server):

`webpack.common.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './client/src/index',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`webpack.development.config.js`:

```
const CommonWebpack = require('./webpack.common.config');

module.exports = {
  ...CommonWebpack,
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  devtool:'inline-source-map'
};
```

`webpack.production.config.js`:

```
const CommonWebpack = require('./webpack.common.config');

module.exports = {
  ...CommonWebpack,
  watch: false,
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: false,
};
```

Have a separate command with the watch for local development. For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "nodemon server",
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.production.config.js",
  "client-development": "webpack --config webpack.development.config.js"
}
```

2. No need for `nodemon` on the server, change your `Procfile` to

```
web: node server/index.js
```

3. The express app has a hardcoded PORT of `3000`. Heroku assigns each app a PORT (via the run environment) according its own internal systems. Change the listen to:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: Having separate config files for the build / client development did the trick, but all the other suggestions were great for cleaning up my files. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @MarissaRomero - glad I could help. I had a quick look at the client - the UI looks great - good luck with the project :)